# Enable/Disable Radio button on dropdown selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to Enable/Disable Radio button on dropdown selected.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/thorstorm1102/1sm2uxtb/6/)

Ex: If `persons` is selected only `name="persons"` must be available to select(Anthony and Paul), Rest must be disabled

```
        <select class="browser-default" id="type" name="type">
        <option value="persons">persons</option>
        <option value="animals">animals</option>
        <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
        </select>

        <br/>

        <label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" >Apple</label>
        <br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="banana" id="banana" >Banana</label>
        <br/>

        <label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="dog" id="dog" >Dog</label>
        <br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="cat" id="cat" >Cat</label>
        <br/>


        <label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="anthony" id="anthony" >Anthony</label>
        <br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="paul" id="paul" >Paul</label>
        <br/>
```

Comment: [Create a minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to make this work, **you just need to check the current value of `select` then make a condition on which input has to be disabled**.

### Pure JS approach

So all you have to do is to make an [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for your `select` element change, then set the condition for disabling the associated `input`s with the same `name` of the selected option. Then with the page [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event, we will just trigger the change event of select with the [event constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) to make sure our event listener runs once in page load.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("type");
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");

window.onload = function() {
  select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
}

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.checked = false;
    if (input.getAttribute("name") !== this.value) {
      input.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    } else {
      input.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<select class="browser-default" id="type" name="type">
  <option value="persons">persons</option>
  <option value="animals">animals</option>
  <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
</select>

<br />

<label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" title="">Apple</label>
<br />
<label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="banana" id="banana" title="">Banana</label>
<br />

<label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="dog" id="dog" title="">Dog</label>
<br />
<label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="cat" id="cat" title="">Cat</label>
<br />


<label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="anthony" id="anthony" title="">Anthony</label>
<br />
<label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="paul" id="paul" title="">Paul</label>
<br />
```

### jQuery approach

This is almost the same as pure approach and it just implemented by jQuery. Here we will listen to the change event of our `select` element, then we will disable all the input and enable all the matched `input`s value with `select` value. In the end, we will call the [`trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) event to make sure our selection will change once in the page load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $("input").prop("checked", false);
    $("input").prop('disabled', false);
    $("input[type='radio']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("input[name='" + $(this).val() + "']").prop("disabled", false);
  }).trigger("change");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="browser-default" id="type" name="type">
  <option value="persons">persons</option>
  <option value="animals">animals</option>
  <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
</select>

<br/>

<label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" >Apple</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="banana" id="banana" >Banana</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="dog" id="dog" >Dog</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="cat" id="cat" >Cat</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="anthony" id="anthony">Anthony</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="paul" id="paul">Paul</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change',function(){
    $('input').attr('disabled',true)
    $('input[name="'+$(this).val()+'"]').removeAttr('disabled')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="browser-default" id="type" name="type">
  <option value="persons">persons</option>
  <option value="animals">animals</option>
  <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
</select>

<br/>

<label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" >Apple</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="banana" id="banana" >Banana</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="dog" id="dog" >Dog</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="cat" id="cat" >Cat</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="anthony" id="anthony" >Anthony</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="paul" id="paul" >Paul</label>
```

But you should change your DOM structure.

Comment: Thanks. Can it be disabled instead of hiding

Comment: You have it now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const type = document.querySelector("#type");
const radios = document.querySelectorAll("#radio-group input[type=radio]");

function toggleDisabled() {
  radios.forEach(r => r.disabled = r.name !== type.value);
}

type.addEventListener("change", toggleDisabled);

toggleDisabled();
```

```html
<select class="browser-default" id="type" name="type">
  <option value="persons">persons</option>
  <option value="animals">animals</option>
  <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
</select>

<br/>

<div id="radio-group">
  <label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" >Apple</label>
  <br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="banana" id="banana" >Banana</label>
  <br/>

  <label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="dog" id="dog" >Dog</label>
  <br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="cat" id="cat" >Cat</label>
  <br/>


  <label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="anthony" id="anthony" >Anthony</label>
  <br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="paul" id="paul" >Paul</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Working*** ***code*** below for `disabled` the radio button on change of values from `select dropdow` based on type of genre.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change',function(){
    $('input').prop('checked', false);
    $('input').prop('disabled', true);
    $('input[name="'+$(this).val()+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="browser-default" id="type" name="type">
  <option value="persons">persons</option>
  <option value="animals">animals</option>
  <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
</select>

<br/>

<label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" disabled="true">Apple</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="banana" id="banana" disabled="true">Banana</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="dog" id="dog" disabled="true">Dog</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="cat" id="cat" disabled="true">Cat</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="anthony" id="anthony">Anthony</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="paul" id="paul">Paul</label>
```